# Get lsmeans from lm model with fix nested effects

Tags: r, lm, interaction, least-squares

I have a model as:

```
model <- lm (Data$Body_wt ~ Area + Owner%in%Area +  Breed + Rank + Age + Breed*Area, Data)
```

if I now want `lsmean` of:

```
lsmeans(model, ~ Breed +Area)
```

I do not get a result (just empty rows); but if I put:

```
lsmeans(model, ~ Age)
```

I do get result. However, I want results for my

```
lsmeans(model, ~ Breed +Area)
```

what should I do? I get it in SAS but not with R?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
lsmeans(model, ~ Breed*Area)
```